# ng-change is not working initially on page loading but after refreshing page it works fine

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Here is the code I am facing problem with:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="TODATE" data-ng-change="setTdate()" name="date" class="form-control datepicker" id="todate"  data-date-container="#cal"  data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"   />
```

code in controller:

```
$scope.setTdate = setTdate;
    function setTdate() 
   { 
     alert("working"); 
   }
```

I am using input type as text for bootstrap datepicker, and wants to call a function on selecting a  date. The ng-change event is not working when the page initially loads but as i refresh the page it works fine. There is no warning or error  on debug.

Comment: I don't see any declaration for `ng-change` in your code, is it added dynamically? If so, can you add the code where it's done? If not, where do you expect the `ng-change` to be triggered?

Comment: @kaddath I have edited the code please review

Comment: @anupriyagupta it would be better if you produce a plucker

Comment: @prashantPimpale created this plunker please have look https://plnkr.co/edit/MZCciHSyfPVnfiQpzRDZ?p=preview

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35178790/7124761

Comment: @prashantPimpale not working on changing the date.. it seems that selected date is not getting updated in $ scope, as if i change ng-change to ng-click it works fine when I  click on textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look. I think it's working fine without refreshing the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="date" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="myValue" />
  <p>ng-change triggered {{count}} times.</p>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.count = 0;
      $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.count++;
      };
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks.. but i am trying to call ng-change on selecting a date from a ui-datepicker.

Comment: i have updated it for type=date you can check it and you should mention while asking

Comment: the date type works fine but as it is a HTML5 control it does not work in IE hence the type is selected as "text" and bootstrap date picker is used.

Comment: i understand. First the function declaration is wrong $scope.abc=function(){ }  not $scope.abc=function abc(){ }

Comment: second after selecting a date value ng-change will work if you chnage the length of string in input field

Comment: please try to change or delete last digit like 8 from 2018 and the function willl work

Comment: and for better result you can use ng-focus also

Comment: hope this helps @anupriya

Comment: made the changes and it is working, but i want this on selecting a new date